# I can't fix function for calculate the final amount for the deposit

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this function for calculate the final amount for the deposit, but the percentage is not calculated:

```
def deposit(start, deposits, percent, years):
    i = 0
    end_deposit = start
    while i < years * 12:
        i  += 1 
        end_deposit += deposits
        if i // 12:
            end_deposit += end_deposit % percent
    print(end_deposit)

x = float(input('Enter start deposit:'))
y = float(input('Enter monthly deposit:'))
z = float(input('Enter percent:'))
a = float(input('Enter for what years deposit:'))

deposit(start=x, deposits=y, percent=z, years=a)
```

When entering an integer percentage, it is not calculated, but when entering a fractional percentage, something strange happens.

[image: Integer percentage]

[image: Fractional percentage]

Comment: Is your actual formatting like it is displayed? Because it is not valid. Can you please first fix the formatting?

Comment: I'm not sure that: `end_deposit % percent` does what you think it does. Please look up the [%](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) operator.

Answer (score 2):

As [quamrana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4834/quamrana) pointed out in a comment, `% percent` isn't calculating the percentage it returns the modulus, instead try  `* percent/100` to get the percentage and use the modulus operator to check the year, like the example below:

```
def deposit(start, deposits, percent, years):
    i = 0
    end_deposit = start
    while i < years * 12:
        i  += 1 
        end_deposit += deposits
        if i % 12 == 0:
            end_deposit += end_deposit * percent/100 # remove /100 if passing a decimal percentage
    print(end_deposit)

x = float(input('Enter start deposit:'))
y = float(input('Enter monthly deposit:'))
z = float(input('Enter percent:'))
a = float(input('Enter for what years deposit:'))

deposit(start=x, deposits=y, percent=z, years=a)
```

Example output:

[image]

In your example image you have an end total of around 948,000, this is equal to `300,000 + (3,000 * 12 * 18)` which means no interest has been taken in to account, with 5% interest annually it should come to around 1.78  million